# Android - an external library changes the whole app name

Tags: android

I have added an external library to my project and becuase it has a @string/app_name tag in its values file it changes my whole app name. I cant edit this values file. And somehow android studio prefer to take the external library app_name resource. How can i fix it?

**Solution:**

as Nicholas Tee said:

> Change the app name in your AndroidManifest.XML under  tag.You should see android:label=@string/app_name resource.
>   In your string.xml, create another tag, let's say @string/app_name_mine.
>   Change the android:label=@string/app_name to android:label=@string/app_name_mine

I have also needed to add an:

```
tools:replace="label"
```

to my application tag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change the app name in your `AndroidManifest.XML` under `<application>` tag.

You should see `android:label=@string/app_name` resource.

In your `string.xml`, create another tag, let's say `@string/app_name_mine`.

Change the `android:label=@string/app_name` to `android:label=@string/app_name_mine`

Answer (score 0):

In the values/strings.xml of your related module:

```
<string name="app_name" translatable="false">MyApplication</string>
```